# div блок с прокруткой

Tags: html, css

Футер и хедер должны быть всегда статичны, а высота дивов регулироваться автоматически, в зависимости от высоты окна. Как можно решить эту проблему?

```css
.wrapper {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    
}

.main {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0% 10%;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

header {
    background-color: gray;
}

footer {
    background-color: gray;
    height: 12px;
}

li {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <header> Text
                <div> 1 </div>
            </header>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <ul>

                    <li>
                        Поскольку низ блока #layout — это карман, он для футера должен быть пустым, не отображающим объекты страницы. И тут встречаемся с ещё одним ограничением — мы не можем делать пустой карман за счёт padding в #layout, потому что тогда он станет больше 100%.
                        Не спасёт и margin — пустоту нужно делать за счёт свойств вложенных элементов.

                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Поскольку низ блока #layout — это карман, он для футера должен быть пустым, не отображающим объекты страницы. И тут встречаемся с ещё одним ограничением — мы не можем делать пустой карман за счёт padding в #layout, потому что тогда он станет больше 100%.
                        Не спасёт и margin — пустоту нужно делать за счёт свойств вложенных элементов.

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Поскольку низ блока #layout — это карман, он для футера должен быть пустым, не отображающим объекты страницы. И тут встречаемся с ещё одним ограничением — мы не можем делать пустой карман за счёт padding в #layout, потому что тогда он станет больше 100%.


                    </li>


                </ul>
            </div>
            <footer> </footer>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <header> Text</header>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <ul>

                    <li>
                        Поскольку низ блока #layout — это карман, он для футера должен быть пустым, не отображающим объекты страницы. И тут встречаемся с ещё одним ограничением — мы не можем делать пустой карман за счёт padding в #layout, потому что тогда он станет больше 100%.
                        Не спасёт и margin — пустоту нужно делать за счёт свойств вложенных элементов.

                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Поскольку низ блока #layout — это карман, он для футера должен быть пустым, не отображающим объекты страницы. И тут встречаемся с ещё одним ограничением — мы не можем делать пустой карман за счёт padding в #layout, потому что тогда он станет больше 100%.
                        Не спасёт и margin — пустоту нужно делать за счёт свойств вложенных элементов.

                    </li>

                    <li>
                        Поскольку низ блока #layout — это карман, он для футера должен быть пустым, не отображающим объекты страницы. И тут встречаемся с ещё одним ограничением — мы не можем делать пустой карман за счёт padding в #layout, потому что тогда он станет больше 100%.
                        Не спасёт и margin — пустоту нужно делать за счёт свойств вложенных элементов.

                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <footer>
            </footer>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: не должна быть прокрутка самой страницы, только блоков

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так:

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  flex: 1 0;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0% 10%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

header {
  background-color: gray;
}

footer {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 12px;
}

li {
  padding: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <header> Text
      <div> 1 </div>
    </header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li>
          Поскольку низ блока #layout — это карман, он для футера должен быть пустым, не отображающим объекты страницы. И тут встречаемся с ещё одним ограничением — мы не можем делать пустой карман за счёт padding в #layout, потому что тогда он станет больше 100%.
          Не спасёт и margin — пустоту нужно делать за счёт свойств вложенных элементов.
        </li>
        <li>
          Поскольку низ блока #layout — это карман, он для футера должен быть пустым, не отображающим объекты страницы. И тут встречаемся с ещё одним ограничением — мы не можем делать пустой карман за счёт padding в #layout, потому что тогда он станет больше 100%.
          Не спасёт и margin — пустоту нужно делать за счёт свойств вложенных элементов.
        </li>
        <li>
          Поскольку низ блока #layout — это карман, он для футера должен быть пустым, не отображающим объекты страницы. И тут встречаемся с ещё одним ограничением — мы не можем делать пустой карман за счёт padding в #layout, потому что тогда он станет больше 100%.
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <footer> </footer>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <header> Text</header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li>
          Поскольку низ блока #layout — это карман, он для футера должен быть пустым, не отображающим объекты страницы. И тут встречаемся с ещё одним ограничением — мы не можем делать пустой карман за счёт padding в #layout, потому что тогда он станет больше 100%.
          Не спасёт и margin — пустоту нужно делать за счёт свойств вложенных элементов.
        </li>
        <li>
          Поскольку низ блока #layout — это карман, он для футера должен быть пустым, не отображающим объекты страницы. И тут встречаемся с ещё одним ограничением — мы не можем делать пустой карман за счёт padding в #layout, потому что тогда он станет больше 100%.
          Не спасёт и margin — пустоту нужно делать за счёт свойств вложенных элементов.
        </li>
        <li>
          Поскольку низ блока #layout — это карман, он для футера должен быть пустым, не отображающим объекты страницы. И тут встречаемся с ещё одним ограничением — мы не можем делать пустой карман за счёт padding в #layout, потому что тогда он станет больше 100%.
          Не спасёт и margin — пустоту нужно делать за счёт свойств вложенных элементов.
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <footer>
    </footer>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!!!)

Comment: а как сделать так, чтобы футеры были на одном уровне?

Comment: @huhu они ведь и так на одном уровне)

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0% 10%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

header {
  background-color: gray;
}

footer {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 12px;
}

li {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <header> Text
        <div> 1 </div>
      </header>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>

          <li>
            Поскольку низ блока #layout — это карман, он для футера должен быть пустым, не отображающим объекты страницы. И тут встречаемся с ещё одним ограничением — мы не можем делать пустой карман за счёт padding в #layout, потому что тогда он станет больше 100%.
            Не спасёт и margin — пустоту нужно делать за счёт свойств вложенных элементов.

          </li>

          <li>
            Поскольку низ блока #layout — это карман, он для футера должен быть пустым, не отображающим объекты страницы. И тут встречаемся с ещё одним ограничением — мы не можем делать пустой карман за счёт padding в #layout, потому что тогда он станет больше 100%.
            Не спасёт и margin — пустоту нужно делать за счёт свойств вложенных элементов.

          </li>
          <li>
            Поскольку низ блока #layout — это карман, он для футера должен быть пустым, не отображающим объекты страницы. И тут встречаемся с ещё одним ограничением — мы не можем делать пустой карман за счёт padding в #layout, потому что тогда он станет больше 100%.


          </li>


        </ul>
      </div>
      <footer> </footer>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <header> Text</header>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>

          <li>
            Поскольку низ блока #layout — это карман, он для футера должен быть пустым, не отображающим объекты страницы. И тут встречаемся с ещё одним ограничением — мы не можем делать пустой карман за счёт padding в #layout, потому что тогда он станет больше 100%.
            Не спасёт и margin — пустоту нужно делать за счёт свойств вложенных элементов.

          </li>

          <li>
            Поскольку низ блока #layout — это карман, он для футера должен быть пустым, не отображающим объекты страницы. И тут встречаемся с ещё одним ограничением — мы не можем делать пустой карман за счёт padding в #layout, потому что тогда он станет больше 100%.
            Не спасёт и margin — пустоту нужно делать за счёт свойств вложенных элементов.

          </li>

          <li>
            Поскольку низ блока #layout — это карман, он для футера должен быть пустым, не отображающим объекты страницы. И тут встречаемся с ещё одним ограничением — мы не можем делать пустой карман за счёт padding в #layout, потому что тогда он станет больше 100%.
            Не спасёт и margin — пустоту нужно делать за счёт свойств вложенных элементов.

          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
      <footer>
      </footer>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```